# Как сложить числа из строки с разделителем / (слэш)?

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть таблица, содержащая следующую информацию:

Table:

1. Первая строка:

3/2/5/1

2. Вторая строка

2/9/4/1

3. Третья строка

5/4

Результат должен быть таким:

1. 1 Строка:
   11
2. 2 Строка:
   16
3. 3 Строка:
   9

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне необходимо убрать разделитель "/", чтобы сложить все числа в строке. Например: строку, содержащую следующие данные:  3/2/5/1, представить как сумму чисел без "/", т.е. 3+2+5+1= 11 и спроектировать данное условие на все строки таблицы.

Comment: Не разговаривай с ботом, это бесполезно.

Comment: Да я только сейчас заметил, что это бот))

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий метод, используя токенизацию через `xmltable()`.

**SQL**

```
with rs(id, tokens) as
( 
    select 1, '3/2/5/1' from dual
    union all
    select 2, '2/9/4/1' from dual
    union all
    select 3, '5/4' from dual
)
select id, sum(cast(trim(COLUMN_VALUE) as int)) as "sum"
from rs, xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(tokens, '/', '","') || '"'))
group by id
```

**Результат**

| id | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 16 |
| 3 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

.Если смотреть в документацию, то можно найти следующие вещи:

```
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions167.htm#SQLRF00697
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions227.htm#SQLRF06140
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить вот такой вариант:

```
with MYTABLE AS (
    select '4/5/6' qw from dual
    union all
    select '4/5/6/7' qw from dual
)
select t.qw,
  SUM(trim(regexp_substr(t.qw, '[^/]+', 1, lvl.column_value))) AS SUMMA
from 
  MYTABLE t,
  table(
    cast(
      multiset(
        select level from dual 
        connect by level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(t.qw, '[^/]+')) + 1
      ) as sys.OdciNumberList
    )
  ) lvl
GROUP BY t.qw;
```